# How can i add components dynamically to an install4j form?

Tags: install4j

I want to add fields to an install4j form when the user clicks on a button.
Can't find any help online or in the documentry... 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add form components dynamically at runtime. You would have to write a form component with the API that implements the desired creation of input fields. See the "customCode" sample project to get started.

Comment: Thanks , I'll check it out